# Single infopath form on submit need to store in multiple list

Tags: list, infopath, submit

I have have 5 lists combined together want to create a single infopath form.

Suppose List A, B,C,D,E ---

List A will have few columns and a dropdown column for B, C,D,E.  Suppose if the user select B from the dropdown it have to load a infopath form for B and on submit should store the data in respective List B.

How to create a infopath form combing all the forms into single LIST A form and how to store to respective lists..

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you only wish to have a form capable of adding items, it's possible through the user of the "Submit to Webservice" functionality & a simple XML template which maps to your fields. Can't find a good blog post on it right now, but code is definitely not necessary (even though this one has it at the end: http://geekswithblogs.net/KunaalKapoor/archive/2012/04/30/how-to-submit-data-from-an-infopath-2010-form-to.aspx You use the XML as a webservice post body template, you can map the fields in there in your info path form and have a button to trigger the service call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think out of the box it is achievable, but with the CodeBehind (Administrator approved forms that are loaded via central admin) you can have your custom logic, but that requires development in C#.